# unable to display data in datatable of jsf

Tags: jsf

I've the data(retrieved from database) in a list but when I use

```
`f:view><html>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{dataList.list}" var="item"  >
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Num" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText style="" value="#{item.myNum}" ></h:outputText>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.myName}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Country"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.myCountry}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable><br>

        </center>
    </body></html></f:view>`
```

it is displaying a blank data table.

Comment: A bit more detail would be helpful. Could you post your file containing the datatable?

Comment: Please also display the <dataTable> header tag.

Comment: thanx for the reply.  does adding a header tag help me in displaying data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound trivial, but you need to add columns:

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{dataList.list}" var="item">
 <h:column>
   <h:outputText value="#{item.myData}">
 </h:column>
 <h:column>
   <h:outputText value="#{item.myOtherData}">
 </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

the `myData` and `myOtherData` names must be members of the list element's underlying object.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [good tutorial for datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html). If you use JSF 2.0 you do not need to register the bean in faces-config.xml. Then you can use [annotations­](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html#giqqz).

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, I have added the list elements but still the data table is empty

Comment: Ok, but your objects do not need the "my" prefix. E.g. item.country if your object's member name is country

Comment: yeah...I've named my members so..I've written a java method which returns the list(contains database data).configured this java class in the faces-config.xml but still i dont get the data displayed. can u guide me if I'm going wrong in configuring or calling java classes

Comment: Your list elements have to be [beans](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html). This means they need getter/setter-Methods (for displaying at least getters).

Comment: my list elements are beans.. I do have both setters and getters. more clearly I have written a java class which connects to database and returns a list.also I have a bean which is configured in the faces-config.xml

Comment: Try to debug and find out if (1) the list is not empty and (2) the getter-Methods of your bean are called

Comment: definetely the list is empty..when i call " value="#{dataList.list}" " it is not getting fetched.. Thats where my problem is..i guess all this depends upon how i configure the respective bean to faces-config.xml or something related in this way..Can pls u guide me in this prospective

Comment: Here is a [good tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) for datatables. If you use JSF 2.0 you do not need to register the bean in faces-config.xml. Then you can use [annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html#giqqz).

Comment: I've tried the same way and you suggested me a similar tutorial.Thanks for your time Handy.